# Developing SaaS mobile app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

My company has developed an iOS app for internal use and some of our clients have seen it and are interested in using the app for their own company.

We were wondering if it was possible to build the app and give the archive to the client for them to re-sign and upload to their own iTunes Connect account. I know we could be added to their account as a team member but we don't really want to be involved as we just want to give them the archive maybe with a few changes like logos, bundle id and forget about it.

Is this something that Jenkins or any other CI can do by building a single app sending the archive to the client and then the client can re-sign the app and upload to their own iTunesConnect account?

Answer (score 0):

In your xCode project just make two **targets** out of your single app project (right click on existing target and pressing "Duplicate") and then change the bundle ID (and App Name if desired) to your company's name.

In result you will have two AppName-Info.plist files that are the same but differs only in bundle identifier:

com.Company1.AppName
com.Company2.AppName

This is the minimum requirement to be changed when uploading the same app to iTunes Connect.

Yes, any modern CI system should handle this. You basically have two apps now but use the same codebase. And yes, you can detect which build you are on from code.

Comment: What about the certificates, can I use my own distribution certificate and then the client can resign the archived app on there end via a local installation of xCode/Application Loader?

Comment: yup. Just as you said. You will have not only two apps with it's xxxx-Info.plist files. You will have two sets of Build settings too. You do there whatever you want (select Distribution profile you need). Your client will need the private keys (Distribution) of course which could be a pain in the ass to import. I would recommend having one machine where the app building for Distribution takes place. Sorry my CI skills are not so good yet. Cant go into details.